# Java Multithreading for Mysql Inserts

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I searched now for a while with google but i could not get it to work. My approach is to have a Multithread software which collects data on one Thread and then execute the batch query for Mysql in a second thread while the first thread is going on collecting data. Goal should it be to use as less RAM as possible for millions of inserts. In My data collection Process i use one Object of MYSQLInsertThread and i insert Data like this:

```
String[] types = {"Long", "Long"};
int[] pos = {1, 1};
Object[] values = {123, 456};

nodeTagsInsertThread.addBatch(types, pos, values);
```

The first call works, if I set the batchCount to 100 i got 104 entrys in my Database but that are the only entrys which my class produces (it should import 5 million entrys!

```
public class MYSQLInsertThread  implements Runnable
{
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName = "MYSQL InsertThread";
    private String query;

    private PreparedStatement pstmt;
    private PreparedStatement pstmt2;

    private long batchCount;
    private long maxBatchAmount;

    private Boolean pstmt1Active = true;
    private Boolean isRunning = false;

    public MYSQLInsertThread(String name, String query, Connection conn, int maxBatchAmount) throws SQLException
    {
        threadName = name;
        this.pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        this.pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        this.query = query;
        this.maxBatchCount = maxBatchAmount;
        System.out.println("Creating Thread: " + name);
    }

    public synchronized void addBatch(String[] types, int[] positions, Object[] values) throws SQLException
    {
        PreparedStatement _pstmt;
        if(pstmt1Active) 
        {
            _pstmt = pstmt;
        }
        else 
        {
            _pstmt = pstmt2;
        }

        if(_pstmt != null)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<types.length; i++) 
            {
                switch(types[i]) 
                {
                    case "string":
                    case "String":
                        _pstmt.setString(positions[i], (String)values[i]);
                        break;
                    case "long":
                    case "Long":
                        _pstmt.setLong(positions[i], (long)values[i]);
                        break;
                    case "int":
                    case "Integer":
                        _pstmt.setInt(positions[i], (int)values[i]);
                        break;
                    case "double":
                    case "Double":
                        _pstmt.setDouble(positions[i], (double)values[i]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            _pstmt.addBatch();
            batchCount++;

            if(batchCount % maxBatchCount == 0) 
            {
                System.out.println("["+ this.threadName +"]Adding " + batchCount + " Entrys to DB" );
                this.executeBatch();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            System.err.println("[MYSQLInsertThread]Error PreparedStatment is NULL, Parameter could not be added");
        }
    }

    public synchronized void executeBatch() 
    {
        PreparedStatement _pstmt;
        if(pstmt1Active) 
        {
            _pstmt = pstmt;
        }
        else 
        {
            _pstmt = pstmt2;
        }

        if(_pstmt != null) 
        {
            if(isRunning)System.out.println("Waiting for previous Batch Execution to finish");
            while(isRunning) 
            {
                System.out.print(".");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            this.start();
            System.out.println("Execution Started Successfully");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.err.println("[" + this.threadName + "]PSTMT is NULL");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        PreparedStatement _pstmt;

        if(pstmt1Active) 
        {
            _pstmt = pstmt;
        }
        else 
        {
            _pstmt = pstmt2;
        }

        if(_pstmt != null) 
        {
            isRunning = true;   

            pstmt1Active = !pstmt1Active;

            try 
            {
                _pstmt.executeBatch();
            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            isRunning = false;  
        }
    }

    public void start()
    {
        if(t == null)
        {
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of swapping two `PreparedStatement` instances like that, I would suggest you get a new `PreparedStatement`. Or just use one and synchronize on it.

Comment: on PreparedStatement should not be capable, if the prepared Statement is executing a Batch i am not really sure if it  would be safe to add new Batches during executiion and if i create a new PreparedStatement i overwrite the running execution, i guess that should kill the running execution

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution now by myself searching a bit through youtube videos :D

I made a new Class which hold my PreparedStatements. If one Statement is executing a flag is preivously set. If the second Statemet wants to execute the Batch now but the previous Statement is still running it makes the collecting thread waiting for a notify of the writing process. The writing process notifys after finishing the execution of the statements!
Here is my Code:

```
public class ThreadPreparedStatement 
{
    private String query;
    private String threadName;

    private PreparedStatement pstmt1;
    private PreparedStatement pstmt2;

    private boolean pstmt1Active;
    private boolean isRunning;

    private long maxBatchAmount;
    private long batchCount;

    public ThreadPreparedStatement(String threadName, String query, Connection conn, long maxBatchAmount) throws SQLException
    {
        this.threadName = threadName;

        this.pstmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        this.pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        this.maxBatchAmount = maxBatchAmount;
        this.query = query;

        this.batchCount = 0;
    }

    public synchronized void addParameters(String[] types, int[] positions, Object[] values) throws SQLException
    {

        PreparedStatement _pstmt;
        if(pstmt1Active) 
        {
            _pstmt = pstmt1;
        }
        else 
        {
            _pstmt = pstmt2;
        }

        if(_pstmt != null)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<types.length; i++) 
            {
                switch(types[i]) 
                {
                    case "string":
                    case "String":
                        _pstmt.setString(positions[i], (String)values[i]);
                        break;
                    case "long":
                    case "Long":
                        _pstmt.setLong(positions[i], (long)values[i]);
                        break;
                    case "int":
                    case "Integer":
                        _pstmt.setInt(positions[i], (int)values[i]);
                        break;
                    case "double":
                    case "Double":
                        _pstmt.setDouble(positions[i], (double)values[i]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            _pstmt.addBatch();
            batchCount++;

            if(batchCount % maxBatchAmount == 0) 
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            executeBatch(_pstmt);
                        }catch(Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();              
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            System.err.print("Error Prepared Statements are both NULL");
        }
    }


    public synchronized void executeAllBatches() 
    {
        try 
        {
            if(isRunning) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    wait(); //wait for finish execution
                }catch(InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
            }
            isRunning = true;

            pstmt1.executeBatch();
            pstmt2.executeBatch();


            isRunning = false;
            notify();
        }catch(Exception e) 
        {

        }
    }


    public synchronized void executeBatch(PreparedStatement _pstmt) throws SQLException 
    {
        System.out.println("["+ this.threadName +"]Adding " + batchCount + " Entrys to DB" );
        if(isRunning) 
        {
            try 
            {
                wait(); //wait for finish execution
            }catch(InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }

        pstmt1Active = !pstmt1Active;
        isRunning = true;
        _pstmt.executeBatch();  //execute Query Batch

        isRunning = false;
        notify();               //notify that Batch is executed
    }

}
```